# R - How to remove rows that don't match values in .csv file

Tags: r

I want to delete all of the records in fpov that do not match one of the zip codes in 'zips'. This is essentially the code I have written:

```
zips <- read.csv("ZIPS.csv")
zipsFM <- data.frame(zips)

fpov <- read.csv("ACS_15_5YR_B01003_with_ann TOTAL POPULATION.csv",skip=1)
fpovFM <- data.frame(fpov)
head(fpovFM)

fpovPARSED <- fpovFM[! fpovFM$Id2 %in% zipsFM,]
head(fpovPARSED)
```

Unfortunately when I run the code, fpovPARSED still has all of the data in it. Am I going about this the right way? Is there a better way to go about removing rows based on values in a .csv file?

EDIT: I took out the ! operator and now I'm getting 0 rows (unless I replace zipsFM with a vector variable that contains a list of values -- then it works) so I still am not sure how to remove the unnecessary rows based on the zips.csv file.

Comment: I will restate your question and tell me if this is correct, you want to keep all rows of fpovFM if the Id2 zip codes matches one of the values in zipsFM?  Why do you have `!`.  It reverses the logicals. Remove `!` and that should get you what you want.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. Hm... not sure why I thought I needed the ! operator. Changed that, but now its giving me zero rows as output...

Comment: I suppose it's worth noting that I just tested the same code, but replaced the variable after %in% with a vector of values and the code worked okay. So I guess the problem has to be in reading the values from the zipsFM data frame.

Comment: Please check if you have leading/lagging spaces

Comment: I actually just ended up solving this by specifying zipsFM$zips (which was the column name). I guess it converted it into a vector then and everything functioned perfectly.